# Can I use OS X Safari browser to properly test iOS Safari browser-specific code using media queries?

Tags: css, ios, ipad, safari, media-queries

I do not own any iOS devices, thus all my web coding development is done on Safari. I've been [trying this awesome project to do my testing](https://github.com/mattkersley/Responsive-Design-Testing), but I'm finding out that it's possibly limited.

Specifically, I want to use [specific media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) within my main CSS so that only the iPad can render the CSS:

```
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

When I try access it via localhost on OS X Safari using the Responsive Testing project using Safari on OS X, it ignores the code. I even tried more specific code for landscape and portrait with no success:

```
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

This wasn't successful either.

Since I don't own the iPad/iPhone, I can only see the result at the Apple Store. Is the code I provided literally only accessible on the iPad and I can't use Safari on my computer to do some initial testing?

Comment: If you download Xcode, there's the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Oh, interesting, I didn't know that. So there's no real way for me to test for iOS without Xcode iOS simulator? I guess this is my best bet for now.

Comment: There might be a way to test without it, but the iOS Simulator probably is the most faithful to the real device (besides the device itself).

Comment: You should be able to simulate some tests with "min/max-width" and Safari (vs device-width) for testing only but certainly that could get messy, so the simulator would be your best option if you can install it. Note that it has iPhone3, iPhone4 and iPad modes so you can detect the different resolutions for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who don't own an iOS device like an iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch, the cheapest/free way to develop without the hardware is to [download XCode and run the iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). You can quickly switch between the devices in the simulator and they load as they would on the devices themselves.

Rock on and thank you to @icktoofay!

Comment: what if i dont have a computer running Macos

Comment: @14jbella Now that it's 2018, there are other methods you can use to test iOS Safari, such as https://www.browserstack.com